# An interesting animation with SwiftUI's LazyVGrid on multiple items insert and remove

Tags: animation, swiftui, scrollview, lazyvgrid

I have a button where let the user see some more of the items on tap. Initially it's shows of 4 items. After tap, I add rest of the items to the list and for less, I just show the first 4 items. The default animation gets weird every time playing with it. It's overlapping, comes from bottom. For demonstration purpose, I have slow down the animations in simulator.

[image]

You can find a demonstration app's source code: https://github.com/nesimtunc/swiftui-playground

Basically this is the whole code.

What's wrong with my implementation? Why this default animation is like this? How can I implement one without side effects?

PS: I have already tried `MatchedGeometry` and it didn't helped.

Thank you!

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ItemModel<T>: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var items: [T]
    let showMoreText: String
    let showLessText: String
    let visibleItemsCount: Int
    
    @Published var visibleItems: [T] = []
    @Published var showAll: Bool = false
    @Published var toggleText: String = ""
    
    init(
        items: [T],
        showMoreText: String,
        showLessText: String,
        visibleItemsCount: Int,
        showAll: Bool = false
    ) {
        self.items = items
        self.showMoreText = showMoreText
        self.showLessText = showLessText
        self.visibleItemsCount = visibleItemsCount
        self.showAll = showAll
        visibleItems = showAll ? items : Array(items.prefix(visibleItemsCount))
        toggleText =  showAll ? showLessText : showMoreText
    }
    
    func toggle() {
        showAll.toggle()
        update()
    }
    
    private func update() {
        visibleItems = showAll ? items : Array(items.prefix(visibleItemsCount))
        toggleText = showAll ? showLessText : showMoreText
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    private var col = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16), count: 2)
    private let visibleItemsCount = 4
    private let spacing: CGFloat = 16.0
    
    @ObservedObject private var model: ItemModel<Int>
    
    init() {
        var newItems = [Int]()
        for i in 0..<10 {
            newItems.append(i)
        }
        self.model = ItemModel(items: newItems,
                               showMoreText: "Show More",
                               showLessText: "Show Less",
                               visibleItemsCount: visibleItemsCount)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: col , alignment: .center, spacing: spacing) {
                ForEach(model.visibleItems, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.orange))
                }
            }
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    model.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                Text(model.toggleText)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                    .background(Capsule().strokeBorder(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 1.5))
            }
            // This is on for demonstartion purpose, using same data but with whole
            LazyVGrid(columns: col , alignment: .center, spacing: spacing) {
                ForEach(model.items, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.sizeCategory, .small)
                .previewDevice("iPhone 13 Pro Max")
                .previewLayout(.device)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to happen? Do you want the additional views to fade in instead of appearing from the bottom?  Something else?

Comment: I expect items should be added from top without overlapping other views (ex: Show More / Show Less button).

Answer (score 1):

LazyVGrid is lazy, its whole content size is not always ready to animate when putting inside a ScrollView. There's a conflict I guess. I would prefer to keep only one LazyVGrid.

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: col , alignment: .center, spacing: spacing) {
            Section(footer: showHideButton) {
                ForEach(model.visibleItems, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.orange))
                }.transaction { $0.animation = nil } // --> this line can be removed
            }
            
            Section {
                ForEach(20...30, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))
                        
                }
            }
        }
    }.padding()
}

@ViewBuilder
var showHideButton: some View {
    Button {
        withAnimation {
            model.toggle()
        }
    } label: {
        Text(model.toggleText)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
            .background(Capsule().strokeBorder(Color.secondary, lineWidth: 1.5))
    }
}
```

[image: result]

There's another thing called Transitions, please also take a look if you need more advance animations
https://www.objc.io/blog/2022/04/14/transitions/

Comment: Thank you! The reason is using a scrollview is that the screen contains another views that's not presented in that code. Didn't not know that we could use section like that inside LazyVGrid. Let me try whole components like that.

Comment: Okay. It seems it's fine for this case. My actual case the 2nd view is not a Grid, list of collapsible sections. So it can't be inside that LazyGrid.

```swift
ScrollView {
                        AccountView()
   BoxMenuView()
   Rectangle()
   SectionMenuView()
  }
struct BoxMenuView: View {
 var body: some View {
  Text(title)
  LazyVGrid(columns: col) {
   Section(footer: toggleButton) {
    DraggableList(items: boxMenuModel.visibleItems) { item in
     BoxMenuItemView(menu: item)
    } moveAction: { from, to in
     moveMenuItem(from, to)
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

```

Comment: then use basic Stacks better i think. No need to care about memory by using lazy stuffs,  if your list is not long.